# why am I getting undefined Stripe key error in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, post, stripe-payments, stripes

I'm new to Stripe and when I setup it up on my Laravel project for testing I'm getting this error doing a post request to the server.
note: I inserted my stripe key and secret in config/services.php and in `.env` file and also enabled OpenSSL and curl in php.ini in wamp

```
{
"code": 0,
"message": "The Stripe API key is not defined!",
"data": null
}
```

and the code where i'm using stripe :

```
 if ($request->is_male){
            $stripe = Stripe::make(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
            $token = $stripe->tokens()->create([
                'card' => [
                    'number' => $request->credit_number,
                    'exp_month' => $request->credit_exp_month,
                    'exp_year' => $request->credit_exp_year,
                    'cvc' => $request->credit_code
                ],
            ]);


            $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
                'email' => $request->email,
            ]);
            $card = $stripe->cards()->create($customer['id'], $token['id']);
            if (!isset($customer['id'])) {
                return ResponseController::error(-150,"invalid customer");
            }
            $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
                'customer'=>$customer['id'],
                'currency' => 'USD',
                'amount' => env("pay_amount"),
                'description' => 'Gyanomi Subscription',
            ]);
            if($charge['status'] != 'succeeded') {

                throw new \Exception($charge);
            }
```

Comment: did you console or dumped your STRIPE_SECRET?

Comment: Make sure you have setup env for secret keys and do an php artisan optimize:clear and php artisan config:cache

Comment: @Sumitkumar I did both but the same error .

Comment: @umerbilal I didn't understand your question

Comment: Kindly look here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781938/cartalyst-stripe-laravel-returns-error-the-stripe-api-key-is-not-defined-when this might be a duplicate question

Comment: its becuase you are taking the key directly from the env file. Create custom config file and then fetch your env file to your config and then access that config in your blade or controller. also make sure to use `php artisan optimize:clear` after these changes.

Comment: @Sumitkumar Same Issue

Comment: @PushkrajJori how can I access it from my config/services.php file

Comment: `config('services.STRIPE_SECRET')` good luck.